# Does SQL Server Integration Services (SQL Server 2016) (SSIS) re-compile C# code every time it's run, or is it cached?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Recently I came across a strange issue where some variables were being assigned incorrectly within a C# task in a DTSX package but where not causing an error in SSIS installed on SQL Server 2012, but did error on SQL Server 2016.

Essentially the bug was as follows:

```
    Variables.ContainerDisable100 = C100;
    Variables.ContainerDisable101 = C101;
    Variables.ContainerDisable102 = C102;
    Variables.ContainerDisable102 = C103;
```

As you can see Variables.ContainerDisable102 should have been Variables.ContainerDisable103. This should cause an error further does the execution of the dtsx package when it is ran. However this did not cause an issue on our local environments as we were using SQL Server 2012, however on SQL Server 2016 this caused the expected error.

My theory is that someone updated the C# code within this dtsx package using Notepad++ rather than Data Tools. This meant the C# code wasn't recompiled and when SQL Server 2012 ran the compiled code it worked fine.

Which leads me on to my question, does SQL Server 2016 SSIS still look at the compiled code or does it look at the uncompiled C# code?

It's a very strange issue and this is the only hunch I have. When I manually opened the C# task in data tools, made a small change and built and saved it the error then occurred in SQL Server 2012, which makes me believe it didn't build correctly previously or it was updated via the XML.

## **Update**

So I've confirmed that the customer install is running the C# code and not the pre-compiled binary. The setup is as follows:

- SQL Server 2016
- SQL Server Integration Services 13.0

When I update the dtsx with notepad++ and only update the C# code and run the package using SQL Server Job Agent it fails. This should not be the case as it should be looking at the precompiled binary. I can't see anything regarding this in Microsofts What's New page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a needle in a haystack kind of issue but I've got to the bottom of it.

There was a bug within the package which I mentioned above, this bug however was not compiled and stored in the dtsx which meant when running locally I did not receive an error.

My local install was using

- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server Integration Services 11.0

However when the customer tried to execute these packages they received errors. There setup was as follows:

- SQL Server 2016
- SQL Server Integration Services 13.0

The packages which they are running was developed in SQL Server Data Tools 2010 with a target version of SQL Server 2012. They were not updated to be ran with SQL Server 2016.

When executing these packages [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017) is smart enough to see the version mismatch and it temporarily upgrades the package in order to run it. When it upgrades the package it re-compiles the C# code which in turn causes the error.

I believe there was an issue during the build of the C# script task or a developer manually updated the C# code via the dtsx XML which meant the pre-compiled C# was never re-compiled which caused this issue to be found.

I hope this helps others avoid this issue in the future.